# Persian text and date are malformed in CrystalReport

Tags: c#

I have a table with a `Nvarchar(max)` field in `SQL Server`. When I read data from the field, and show it in `CrystalReport`,  the data is presented incorrectly.

For example, the data in the table is

> تست تاریخ 1394/09/12

But it shows up in CrystalReport as

> تست تاریخ 12/09/1394

The object format in CrystalReport is righttoleft and I have set the object to *Can Grow*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can format the result this way:

`.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")`

[fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e8YAJH)

Comment: can you help me more?

Comment: I do not understand about your answer

Comment: Just format the date that way I mentioned then pass the result as a string to your report :)